Is it pythonic for a decorator to change the return value/type?
I have encounter a pattern in a code base that do the following:
def function():
    """
    A function that do something, and return True if no exception occurred, False otherwise.
    """
    try:
        # Do whatever it should
        return True
    except:
        return False


And I have decided that it can be solved by a decorator, that handles the exception:
def false_if_exception(func):
    """
    Make the function return True if it goes without exceptions
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"DEBUG: an exception thrown while calling {func.__name__}:  {e}")
            return False
        return True
    return wrapper

# Then it can be used like this

@false_if_exception
def function():
    ....

But we have an argument in our team, that decorators should not do this, But I found it totally fine and pythonic myself.
Is it pythonic to do this?

Your decorator will not work as you expect because an exception will never be raised within the wrapper function. Even if there is a exception raised within function this will not affect wrapper which ignores the value being returned from function. Also the form of the Exception within function is lost and will not be known to wrapper.
